# CentOS 8.2 failing to boot on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, centos, centos-8

I'm trying to install the latest CentOS, 8.2.2004, on VirtualBox and it's failing at this point:

[image]

I have tried the three images, dvd, boot and minimal, same results.

The full VirtualBox config is:

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong here?

I tried removing `rd.live.check` from the boot options just in case, same result.

I tried disabling SELinux by adding `selinux=0` at boot, no difference.